# Split an array into chaotic sub-arrays?

Tags: random, arrays

There is a need to split a data array consisting of *n* rows and *m* columns into *s* non-intersecting parts of (approximately) equal size.

Realistically *n*m* is not necessarily divisible by *s* so we have to work with blocks of size *floor(n*m)* and *ceil(n*m)*. However at the moment this is the least of my concerns.

The essential required property is that every block is structurally disconnected from the wholeness of data in a sense that neither large chunks of globally adjacent elements belong to the same block nor it is a checker-board style splitting.

What would you suggest? Should I simply turn to randomness or are there some neat structures suitable in this situation?

Comment: Might be a good idea to make it clear you're using php here (if, indeed, that is the case.)

Comment: @FarmerGedden Thanks for your comment. I am actually testing and visualizing results using MatLab. Anyway ideas and/or pseudo-code would be just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found myself idly mulling this over during snatched periods of downtime, and it seems like there should be a few ways to do it; it somewhat depends on what you want to achieve. Here's what I've been dreaming up, in case it's useful.

As I understand this, you'd like to divide up an *n x m* array up into *i* roughly equal chunks, where *n* and *m* are unknown, and without any adjacent elements sharing a set.

Firstly, the [Four Colour theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem) tells us that you can do this with four sets; it might be worth seeing if there's an existing algoritm for working these out for an array. On the other end of the scale, you can trivially do this for *n x m* groups, by assigning each element it's own singleton set.

How you approach this rather depends on what you'd like to minimise - whether you want the smallest number of groups *i*, for example. If this wasn't an issue, you could try something like the following:

Looking at *n* alone, If n is even, divide the array into sets of size *n/2*, then create *n/2* sets - one containing the 1st element of each group, one containing the 2nd etc. These will contain only non-consecutive elements. If *n* is odd, create a singleton set consisting of the *nth* element, and then proceed as above with the remainder.

In the one - dimensional case, this will give you *n/2* sets of size 2, with a potential extra set of size 1. It will work with 2 dimensions as well, dividing both *n* and *m* up as above.

As said, this probably isn't the answer you were looking for, but I hope it might help promote further investigation - you could replace the odd / even check for one for the highest common factor or prime decomposition, for example. It might also be worth asking about this on [Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/).

I can write up some pseudocode (or some python) as to how the above might be possible, if that would be useful.